# Remove a laravel passport user token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

In my unit test, I have a user for whom I generate a token:

```
$tokenString = $this->user->createToken('PHPunit', ['example'])->accessToken;
```

How can I afterward delete this user's token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I do when a user logged out.

```
public function logout() {
    Auth::user()->tokens->each(function($token, $key) {
        $token->delete();
    });

    return response()->json('Successfully logged out');
}
```

This code will remove each token the user generated.

Comment: "message": "Trying to get property 'tokens' of non-object",

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this can revoke the token:

```
$this->user->token()->revoke()
```

Based on [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-how-can-i-manually-revoke-access-token?page=1).

Comment: "message": "Undefined property: App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController::$user",

Comment: @MHFuad, don't you do some research before adding your comments here on SO?

Comment: @VishalParkash. yes, i have

Comment: @MHFuad Ok, but the kind of error message you are posting are very easy to fix if you do some research.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Sanctum documentation stated 3 different ways to revoke tokens. you can find it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#revoking-tokens).
but for most cases we just revoke all user's tokens via:

```
// Revoke all tokens...
auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
```

note: for some reason intelephense gives an error saying tokens() method not defined but the code works fine. [Hirotaka Miyata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7344256/hirotaka-miyata) found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580333/19561535).
so the over all logout method can be something like this:

```
public function logout()
{
    //the comment below just to ignore intelephense(1013) annoying error.
    /** @var \App\Models\User $user **/
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->tokens()->delete();

    return [
        'message' => 'logged out'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**the best working solution is this**

```
public function logout(LogoutRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        if(!$user = User::where('uuid',$request->uuid)->first())
            return $this->failResponse("User not found!", 401);

        try {
            $this->revokeTokens($user->tokens);

            return $this->successResponse([

            ], HTTP_OK, 'Successfully Logout');

        }catch (\Exception $exception) {
            ExceptionLog::exception($exception);

            return $this->failResponse($exception->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function revokeTokens($userTokens)
    {
        foreach($userTokens as $token) {
            $token->revoke();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()
        ->tokens
        ->each(function ($token, $key) {
            $this->revokeAccessAndRefreshTokens($token->id);
        });

    return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);
}

protected function revokeAccessAndRefreshTokens($tokenId) {
    $tokenRepository = app('Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository');
    $refreshTokenRepository = app('Laravel\Passport\RefreshTokenRepository');

    $tokenRepository->revokeAccessToken($tokenId);
    $refreshTokenRepository->revokeRefreshTokensByAccessTokenId($tokenId);
}
```

Comment: Note that this comment is referenced at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-how-to-revoke-and-delete-refresh-token?reply=622432

Answer (score 1):

The problem with these answers is, you are deleting all the tokens if the same user has 2 or more sessions opened in different browsers/devices.

I think it's better to use

```
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
```

So, this is the code I'm using in my API:

```
    public function logout()
    {
         
        auth()->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
    
        return ['message' => 'Desconexión exitosa'];
    
    }
```

It's possible also to delete an specific token

```
$user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->delete();
```

Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#revoking-tokens