# Laravel 8: undefined method 'createToken' intelephense(1013)

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-passport, intelephense

I have a problem with PHP intelephense, the method **createToken** is undefined. i don't know how to fix it. but when I run it in postman it works. i don't know why vscode doesnt recognize it. i also add the **use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;** and **use HasApiTokens** in user model. please help me, I'm running out of options. thank you guys

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $login = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);
    if (!Auth::attempt($login)){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'error']);
    }
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token]);
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and solved by adding the line. For my case.

```
    /** @var \App\Models\MyUserModel $user **/
    $user = Auth::user();
```

I think the annotation line tell PHP intelephense that `$user` variable is not `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` type but `\App\Models\MyUserModel` type. Please try it.

Comment: A simple yet useful solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

in the model User add

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasApiTokens;
}
```

try and tell me

Comment: what's the problem? I'm trying to help you and you're giving me a minus 1? I assure you that this way you won't get far in programming

Comment: tell me what the problem is and I will help you

Comment: @landrymoutongo I think you got a minus because the OP has mentioned in question that the HasApiTokens trait is already added in the User model. So your answer gives an impression that you wrote this answer without reading the question carefully.